# React Js AwesmeSlider Autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hey im a bit new to React. I found this slider which I have implemented and it works fine.

https://caferati.me/demo/react-awesome-slider

My only issue now is I would like it to Autoplay but it seems I cant wrap my head around it. As I understand I need to make a function which will do it for me?

My code so far is.

```
class Slider extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

<div className="slider">
    <AwesomeSlider cssModule={styles}  onFirstMount={slider}>
        <div data-src={image2}>
            <div className="sliderText">
                <div>
                    <h1>Text For first sike</h1>
                    <NewsletterButton className="clickMe" text={I18n.t('ClickMe')}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-src={image4}>
            <Fade left duration={2300}>
                <img className="sliderImage2" src={image3}/>
            </Fade>
            <Zoom duration={2000}>
                <div className="sliderText2">
                    <h1> Text For Slide2 </h1>
                    <p>Slide 2 Paragraph</p>
                </div>
            </Zoom>
        </div>
        <div data-src={image4}>
            <Zoom duration={2000}>
                <div className="sliderText3">
                    <h1> Slide3 </h1>
                    <p>Slider 3 paragrah</p>
                </div>
            </Zoom>
            <Fade bottom duration={2300}>
                <img className="sliderImage3" src={image1}/>
            </Fade>
        </div>
    </AwesomeSlider>
</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Slider;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the below approach a try:

1. Create a timer (as you are looking for an autoplay) which runs for every 2 seconds or so and call a method named `setNextImage` in it.
   In your `componentDidUpdate()`,

   `setTimeout(this.setNextImage, 2000);`
2. In your method write some logic to update state.

   `setNextImage: function() {
      // setState method is used to update the state
         let index = this.state.currentIndex; 
         if(index == yourMax_Image_Count)
            index == 1
         this.setState({ : this.state.currentIndex -1 });
   },`
3. I see there is a attribute `selected` in AwesomeSlider and you can set `this.state.currentIndex` as its value

Make sure you are handling timeout properly.

Comment: function transitionStart(slider) {
  const divs = slider.nextSlide.querySelectorAll('div');
  const color = getComputedStyle(divs[0]).backgroundColor;
  window.transitionUpdateTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    slider.element.style.setProperty('--control-bullet-active-color', shadeRGBColor(color, -0.15));
    slider.element.style.setProperty('--control-bullet-color', color);
  }, 400);
}

I found thois on the page but it returns me an error.

Comment: Any reason to opt querySelectorAll("") ... kind of syntax? I see its javascript.. I hope we can do it in react way.
Would it be possible to provide a snippet for your changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can get next button with jQuery and use click() function like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
       $(".button_class").click();
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: on demo page its actually the startup page a bit different.

Comment: I would not introduce jQuery into React components.

Comment: you can do the same with javascript 

"document.getElementsByClassName("button_class")[0].click();"

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
    const interval = setInterval(this.handleNextSlide, 12500);
    this.interval = interval;   }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.interval != null) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }   }

  handleNextSlide = () => {
    const { dataSource } = this.props;
    const { currentIndex } = this.state;
    if(currentIndex == (dataSource && dataSource.length) - 1) {
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: 0
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex + 1
      });
    }   }

  render() {
    const { dataSource } = this.props;
    const { currentIndex } = this.state;
    return (
      <AwesomeSlider
        selected={currentIndex}
        cssModule={AwsSliderStyles}
      >
        {dataSource && dataSource.map((value, key) => {
          return (
            //Do some stuff.
          );
        })}
      </AwesomeSlider>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this by importing "withautoplay"

```
import withAutoplay from 'react-awesome-slider/dist/autoplay' 

const AutoplaySlider = withAutoplay(AwesomeSlider)
```

and use autoplay tag in your component

```
<AutoplaySlider
        play
        cancelOnInteraction={false} // should stop playing on user interaction
        interval={6000}
      >
        <div data-src=/path/to/image.png />
        <div data-src=/path/to/image.png />
        <div data-src=/path/to/image.png />
      </AutoplaySlider>
```

you can follow this link for more details https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-awesome-slider